# WSS self signing and getting signed certificates

Tags: ssl, websocket

So I made a WebSocket app and deployed it on a server. I have no intension of setting a domain or anything its just sitting on a public IP and listens to stuff. Now, the clients I made were hosted on a different server where I host my personal work.
Now when I got to connect using either chrome or Firefox  I get this error

```
controller.js:61 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://....com/sanboxes/controller/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:5500/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

which makes sense, but when I tried to get a self signed SSL certificate - Chrome didn't like that. What are the alternatives that I have without breaking the bank to get a certificate ?
Also how is it that the personal website which I also signed using lets encrypt opens up on chrome?

Comment: If you’re already using Let’s Encrypt then that’s probably the easiest option for this also

Comment: but lets encrypt dosent let me ssl an IP address for a websocket connection

Comment: for example here I think the tutorial says I need a domain https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/windows-other